# Change Splash Screen according to Festival

Tags: android, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen

I am developing a Video application which also has a Splash Screen. First time when the application starts it will to show the Image stored in Res Folder in Android Studio. Next time when user opens the app it should show the Splash Screen the is pushed via CDN onto the app.

Eg: Splash Screen that changes according to the festival.

If is it possible? How it can be achieved?

Comment: call api which contain flag, apply condition based on flag and set images from resources.

Comment: A source code that could be of some help @HemantParmar

Comment: well i don't have any source code.